# innodb_buffer_pool_size not reducing iowait

Tags: mysql, database-performance

I'm seeing a large amount of iowait CPU usage by the `mysqld` process when running queries on my server.  I've read about the `innodb_buffer_pool_size` settings and that making this value higher than the default 128M should have a positive impact on reducing iowait (since it will cache database information in memory).

I have changed the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to 3GB (and have validated the setting by checking the variables in a running `mysql`), and the virtual memory use of my `mysqld` process has increased accordingly, but I'm still seeing very high iowait figures (and mysql only has a small resident memory footprint).

Is there something else other than `innodb_buffer_pool_size` that could help to reduce iowait (for read operations).

Comment: @BK435 yes, I ran `SELECT TABLE_NAME, ENGINE FROM information_schema.TABLES where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'mydatabase';` and all tables are `InnoDB`.  Also `tmpdir` is set to `/tmp`

Comment: Do you have 3GB of RAM available for the pool? System specs would definitely help here..

Comment: Machine has 8GB of memory in total, and 6GB free.  The only process using any CPU is the `mysqld` process - most of it reported as iowait by `top`. iowait goes between 50%-90% while the queries are running.

Comment: Hmm.  I just ran a 'show processlist' while some of the mysql queries were running, and `Copying to tmp table`, `checking query cache for query` and `removing tmp table` are some states that were reported.  Are temp tables put in the cache, or could these be causing the io wait?

Comment: How big is your DB? If it fits entirely within the size of your pool, you can force mysql to read everything in by analysing or checksumming the tables you use most. I do that if I have recently restored a DB from a backup.

Comment: re: tmp tables - Potentially you don't have the right indexes? Explain your queries and it'll help let you what is going on.

Comment: @DavidK-J Database is ~2GB - I was hoping these changes would have the effect of making it an faux "in memory" db.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85352/discussion-between-david-k-j-and-john-farrelly).

Comment: Set long_query_time = 1; turn on the slowlog; wait a day; run pt-query-digest against the slowlog; then let's figure out who the first couple of them are so slow and why they are using tmp tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that one of the queries I was running had an `Order By` clause in it, and because of the size of data I was returning, the `Order By` forced the sorting to be done on disk (not in memory).  My fix was to remove the `Order By` from the query, and do the sorting in the memory of my application instead.